# Active directory won't replicate permissions in sharepoint wss 3.0

Tags: sharepoint

I have WSS 3, AD is setup with users, those users are added to the WSS 3 site, I can login with any of the AD users, but if they have a permission level lower than "system administrator" they can't access a folder or item in that folder. How do I get lower permissions to replicate?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Permissions are seperate to AD permissions - you will need to set permissions on the SharePoint site/list to give access to an AD (or SharePoint) group that the users do belong to.